# Unwanted Horizontal Scrolling space at end of <ul> <li>

Tags: css, html, whitespace, horizontal-scrolling

I can't manage to get rid of this unwanted horizontal scrolling space at the end of my unordered.. list
I've followed a few tutorials yielding no results. Any idea's what could be wrong?

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [goawaymom.com](http://goawaymom.com/grr.png))</sub>

Click on image to go to View the problem

Thanks in advance if anyone knows what's wrong!

Comment: Yes, it doesn't appear on all screen resolutions, however mostly when zoomed in a tiny bit the horizontal scrolling bar appears.

Comment: I posted a new screen cap to better illustrate the issue jo8691

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.megamenu > li {
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out 0s;
    border: medium none;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 13px;
}
```

im not sure if this is your question/problem.. but i changed the padding to 13px instead of 68. fixed it for me

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't fix the horizontal whitespace to the right of the list.

Comment: im not sure i understand what you're asking.. you want the "HOME" button to be at the left side without any space?

Comment: No, i want all the list items to be centered evenly. However horizontal scrolling space appears when the screen resolution is slightly zoomed in. If you have a larger screen You may not notice this issue.

Comment: I posted a new screencap to better illustrate the issue

Comment: if i remove 'width: 1280px;' in your .body class, the horizontal scrollbar dissapears. ofcourse then the buttons arent aligned, so you can change the font-size to 0.8em in the .megamenu class to fix this.